# MS Excel: How to set 'not equal to' in the range criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose you have a list of records:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |  A  |  B  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  | 100 |  x  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  2  |  50 |  x  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  3  |  30 |  y  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  4  | 180 |  z  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  5  | 140 |  k  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

You want to get sums of all of them, grouped by the value in column `B`.
But you have an already predefined list of values, for which you want to have sums:

```
+-----+-------+-----+
|     |   C   |  D  |
+-----+-------+-----+
|  1  | x     | 150 | < =SUMIF(B1:B;C1;A1:A)
+-----+-------+-----+
|  2  | y     |  30 | < =SUMIF(B1:B;C2;A1:A)
+-----+-------+-----+
|  3  | other | 320 | < =???
+-----+-------+-----+
```

Getting the total sum for `x` and `y` is easy: you can use `SUMIF(B1:B;C1;A1:A)` in column `D` to get total for `x` and so on.

**But how to get the total sum for all the records that are neither `x` nor `y` (in this case they're `z` and `k`) to print it in `D3` cell?**

Comment: `SUM (A:A)-SUM (C1:C2)`?

Comment: Nice solution, @MátéJuhász

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution by Máté Juhász in the comments is an excellent method.  But another way of using a `NOT AND` criteria in this situation, which may be applicable to other problems, is to use `SUMPRODUCT`  or `SUMIFS`

For example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B:B<>C1)*(B:B<>C2)*A:A)
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"<>"&C1,B:B,"<>"&C2)
```

Comment: So, `C1`, `C2` in these formulas can be written only in a static way, right? No way to iterate over C1:C(n-1)? I thought, maybe there is a way to tell Excel "sum values in column A if corresponding value in column B is not in the range C1:C2"

Comment: @Girafa To accomplish that particular process, you  could use the solution mentioned by @MátéJuhász.  Mine is a different method that may be applicable in situations where his is not.  For example, if you wanted to exclude just `x` and `z`.  Or if you did not have the ones to be excluded summed up in a range.